# Alternative for ifstream (c++) whilst trying to read a .wav file in android

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, mfcc

I am trying to compute MFCC coefficients from wav files stored on the SD card. I am using the library: https://github.com/dspavankumar/compute-mfcc

The input is the wav file path using ifstream. I need to be able to access different pcm files split from a single wav file according to time segments and compute the MFCC for each segment. I am having trouble finding a way to get this data (raw pcm data) into the buffer shown in the method below from the java class. (Using JNI)

```
int process (std::ifstream &wavFp, std::ofstream &mfcFp) {
    // Read the wav header    
    wavHeader hdr;
    int headerSize = sizeof(wavHeader);

    wavFp.read((char *) &hdr, headerSize);

    // Check audio format
    if (hdr.AudioFormat != 1 || hdr.bitsPerSample != 16) {
        std::cerr << "Unsupported audio format, use 16 bit PCM Wave" << 
    std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Check sampling rate
    if (hdr.SamplesPerSec != fs) {
        std::cerr << "Sampling rate mismatch: Found " << hdr.SamplesPerSec << " instead of " << fs <<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialise buffer
    uint16_t bufferLength = winLengthSamples-frameShiftSamples;
    int16_t* buffer = new int16_t[bufferLength];
    int bufferBPS = (sizeof buffer[0]);

    // Read and set the initial samples        
    wavFp.read((char *) buffer, bufferLength*bufferBPS);
    for (int i=0; i<bufferLength; i++)
        prevsamples[i] = buffer[i];        
    delete [] buffer;

    // Recalculate buffer size
    bufferLength = frameShiftSamples;
    buffer = new int16_t[bufferLength];

    // Read data and process each frame
    wavFp.read((char *) buffer, bufferLength*bufferBPS);
    while (wavFp.gcount() == bufferLength*bufferBPS && !wavFp.eof()) {
        mfcFp << processFrame(buffer, bufferLength);
        wavFp.read((char *) buffer, bufferLength*bufferBPS);
    }
    delete [] buffer;
    buffer = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

`

It seems like i cant access the wav file on the sd card directly from the c++ library. So i have tried passing in a jbytearray and converting it to char* using:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_nikhar_mst04v10_RecordActivity_doMFCC(JNIEnv *env, jobject 
instance,
                                                   jbyteArray wavBytes_) {
int len = env ->GetArrayLength(wavBytes_);
char* buf = new char[len];
env->GetByteArrayRegion(wavBytes_,0,len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte *>(buf));

// TODO

 /* env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(wavPath_, wavPath);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(mfccPath_, mfccPath);*/
// Assign variables
int numCepstra =  12;
int numFilters =  40;
int samplingRate = 16000;
int winLength = 25;
int frameShift = 10;
int lowFreq = 50;
int highFreq = samplingRate/2;

// Initialise MFCC class instance
MFCC mfccComputer (samplingRate, numCepstra, winLength, frameShift, 
numFilters, lowFreq, highFreq);
mfccComputer.process(buf);
}
```

but this has been unsuccessful. Any suggestions to how i can Accomplish this?

Comment: Note: i have modified the params for mfccComputer to be (const* char wavBytes)

Comment: *It seems like i cant access the wav file on the sd card* Note: we have 2017 and the Android 6 was introduced in 2015 so you had 2 years to get know what were changed. It's obviously problem with permissions not with ifstreams

Comment: This is the first time im using android. Its just for a specific purpose so im learning as im going

Comment: *This is the first time im using android* It doesnt change the fact that you should do some research before asking

Comment: I have tried quite hard, but maybe my inexperience  has led me to miss the answer i was looking for

Comment: In the code you posted, you define `int process (std::ifstream &wavFp, std::ofstream &mfcFp)`, but you call some *other* `process()` method: `mfccComputer.process(buf);`  Please post the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-012/

to get familiar with passing arrays between Java and C.

As for jbyte - this type is machine dependent. Typically, it will be "signed char". I suggest to pass your data to C, and then, cast array to char*. It should work.

But! Make sure to double check how jbyte is declared in case of your target system. You can find it here: $YOUR_PLATFORM_NAME/jni_md.h

Comment: _"As for jbyte - this type is machine dependent."_ It shouldn't be. Oracle specifies it as _signed 8 bits_: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

Comment: From jni.h - /* jni_md.h contains the machine-dependent typedefs for jbyte, jint and jlong */